# How to deal with an unhygienic human subject?

Tags: ethics, etiquette, audio-video-recording, experiment-design

The human subject that I really depend on is extremely unhygienic. Not simply sweaty way, but full-on stench, black teeth and dirty clothes.

I feel responsible for the lab equipment and space that I am going to use for my audio recording with him and I don't know what to do in such situation.

Anyone encountered such problems in their research? Is there any way professionally and politely ask someone to clean themselves up?

Any advice on how to deal with such a situation will be very appreciated.

Comment: Regardless of the ethics/etiquette of it all, something to keep in mind is that if you make being clean a condition of participation then your participant may withdraw. This may not be desirable if you "depend" on them. Sounds like you might just have to accept their poor hygiene.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about academia. It may be on topic in workplace.SE.

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov is research on human subjects on topic on the Workspace SE? I doubt so.

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov issues regarding human subject research are definitely on topic here. This question is not about interacting with a coworker, but rather a participant where all interactions need to be approved by an IRB.

Comment: @CapeCode Thank you for clarification - I misinterpreted the meaning of a "human subject" in this context. I retracted my vote to close.

Comment: I'm voting to close, not because it's an inappropriate question for this site, but because to me your question is not clear.  Please edit the question to explain how the subject's poor personal hygiene puts the lab equipment and space in jeopardy.  Are you concerned about exoparasites, or what?  If you are experiencing a feeling of disgust, and there is no actual danger to the lab or equipment, that is a separate question.  Bottom line, please clarify.

Comment: @aparente001 My question was how to communicate non-insultingly the "please wash up for my experiment" message.  
I will have to record in our EEG booth with the air conditioning off (too noisy for recording), since it has the professional audio equipment and sound isolation. Since the recording is ±3 hours, I am concerned that the smell will persist afterwards. I had an interview with him in a seminar room and I had to intensely air it for a complete day, since my colleagues who entered the room after were feeling sick from the smell that lingered.

Comment: That's helpful clarification.  I think you should edit the the question and especially the title, to focus clearly on the smell and the effect it has on you and the others who use that space.

Comment: @aparente001 Thanks for your tips! Sorry, I'm new to the community. I thought that not focusing on the smell makes the question more general, and hence more helpful to other people, who might have problems similar in some way.

Comment: Well, I do understand the smell being the main problem, or perhaps the only problem.  The part I was having trouble understanding was the *hygiene*.  I was taking it to mean "conditions or practices conducive to maintaining health and preventing disease, especially through cleanliness."  I think you should edit that word out and just focus on the smell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Just put up with it.**

It may be an unpleasant situation for you and others in the lab, but you haven't mentioned any significant negative consequences of his lack of hygiene; nor can I think of any.  I would just tolerate it.  If necessary, clean any dirty surfaces in the lab after each session.  You could also warn others to vacate the area when he is around, if it is harming others' work environment.

Your research is dependent on the subject's good will and participation.  So I would not do anything that risks his ongoing involvement.  Keep in mind that this is unlikely to be something that can be solved easily--this person is already causing unpleasantness to everyone else around him and yet persists in this behavior.